# Почему стек не очищается и происходит "Ошибка сегментирования"?

Tags: c, стек, memory-management

```
#include <stdio.h>

void s()
{
  double f[1000000] = {0.f};
  getchar();
}

int main(void)
{
  s();
  
  double e[90000] = {0.f};
  getchar();

  return 0;
}
```

Почему?

> Ошибка сегментирования (стек памяти сброшен на диск)

Ведь после того как отработает функция стек снова свободен, почему он не очищается?

```
int main(void)
{
  {
    double e[90000] = {0.f};
  }
    
  s();

  getchar();

  return 0;
}
```

Так тоже не работает.

И ещё, я раньше думал что используя маленькие типы данных как `short` и  `char` я буду экономить память но ведь это не так. Мы мало что экономим, ведь если память под стек выделяется с созданием потока и она фиксированного размера(уже выделено какое то количество и от создания переменно ничего не убудет), то какой смысл не использовать везде `int` или если не хватает `long long`? Процессор с ними работает быстрее и память не заполниться ведь это стек, он потом очиститься 

Как экономить память? Единственно что приходит на ум то что "тратят" память глобальные и статические переменные/массивы и строки(хоть создавай массив строк или используй указатель, возвращай функцией, да просто выведи printf-ом все равно будут `static` в `read-only` сегменте. Ну и malloc

Comment: Ну, память под стек не выделяется с созданием потока. Она выделяется по мере того, как мы кладём что-то в стек, ядро будет выделять новые страницы для потока. Фиксированного размера только максимальный размер стека (8 мегабайт по-умолчанию в Linux), а не сам размер стека в определенный момент времени.

Comment: К слову, размера стека самого ядра Linux действительно имеет фиксированный размер, который зависит от архитектуры. На x86 это или 4KiB или 8KiB, т. е. или она или две страницы.

Comment: То есть вы хотите сказать, что если убрать `double e[90000] = {0.f};`, то все работает?

Comment: да, именно это и хочу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Размер стека скорее всего у вас 8 мегабайт. В начале функций выделяется место в стеке для всех переменных заранее. *(Для экономии размера кода и времени.)* В конце каждой функции указатель на вершину стека возвращается назад.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void s()
{

// в начале функции выделяется в стеке память для f : + 8000000 байт

  double f[1000000] = {0.f};
  getchar();

// в конце функции освобождается в стеке память : - 8000000 байт

}

int main(void)
{

// в начале функции выделяется в стеке память для e : + 720000 байт

  s();
  
  double e[90000] = {0.f};
  getchar();

// в конце функции освобождается в стеке память : - 720000 байт

  return 0;
}
```

Чтобы экономить память стека нужно переменные переносить в функции. Стек очищается после завершения функций.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void s()
{

// в начале функции выделяется в стеке память для f : + 8000000 байт

  double f[1000000] = {0.f};
  getchar();

// в конце функции освобождается в стеке память : - 8000000 байт

}

void fe(){

  // в начале функции выделяется в стеке память для e : + 720000 байт

  double e[90000] = {0.f};
  getchar();

  // в конце функции освобождается в стеке память : - 720000 байт

  }

int main(void)
{

  s();
  
  fe();    

  return 0;
}
```

В этом случае в `main` не выделяется заранее место в стеке на 720000 байт. Это происходит только при вызове функции `fe`.

Comment: *"Размер стека 8 мегабайт."* Лучше указывать, на какой ОС.

Comment: Упоминание на статические функции всего лишь даёт понять, что `inline` функции - не подходят. Это просто оборот речи. @Vladimir

Comment: Не очищается он.

Comment: Ассемблер говорит, что чистит : `addq $7999888, %rsp`  @eri

Comment: @AlexGlebe как работает strtok? Указатель на стеке остается же

Comment: Addq это перенос "указателя на вершину стека" а не очистка

Comment: Вопрос и заключался в том, что размер стека не уменьшается а увеличивается. Пример как это исправить я и привёл. @eri

Comment: @AlexGlebe А что насчет использования меньших типов данных? Используя к примеру "short array[some_size]" в функции тем самым я экономлю память лишь для остальных локальных переменных в этой же функции. Я прав? Тогда получается что лучше использовать типы кратные машинному слову.

Comment: Просто уменьшиться размер занятой памяти стека. Сильнее это отразиться в рекурсивном вызове функции. @Зелимхан Магомадов

Comment: Получается осторожничать нужно лишь с выделением в куче? Теперь я не вижу смысла использовать тот же "short" если только не в рекурсии

Comment: В куче всегда память вам выделится, а стек иногда заканчивается. Как правило большие массивы берутся с помощью `malloc`.

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь я смотрю на все это по-иному.

Comment: @ЗелимханМагомадов шорты компилятор запишит через int на 64 разрядных системах.

Comment: `sizeof(short[1000]) == sizeof(int[1000])` - вы не правы. В два раза меньше будет. @eri

Comment: ну да, перепутал немного... со структурами - там выравнивание...